# Netbeans can't resolve symbol c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans

I use Netbeans 8.0. And when c++11 standard turned on it can't resolve vectors methods like push_back or size. It doesnt show any documentation about these methods and it highlights them like errors. But it compiles good and works right.
Here it is a simple example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV5RZ.png

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Strange, since C++11 is supported in NetBeans since version 7.2: http://www.softpedia.com/progChangelog/NetBeans-IDE-Changelog-67804.html

Comment: Don't link to an picture of your code, but post your code.

Comment: it is to show that Netbeans highlights an error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so I needed to add a number of include directories into the dialog box Tools -> Options -> C/C++ -> Code Assistance -> C++ Compiler:
[image]